# Is sulfuric acid necessary for Kevlar synthesis?

Tags: solutions

In the production of Kevlar, the 2 monomers needed for its creation are reacted in a solution. Due to it being water-insoluble, sulfuric acid is used. My question: Can other chemicals be used as well (for examplke salicyclic acid), or is sulfuric acid absolutely necessary? Is there maybe a benefit to using it, or is it simply the cheapest?

Comment: I think you need to tell us more about the process before we can answer this

Comment: It's not for synthesis, but for spinning out of solution.

Comment: The sulfuric acid isn't just required to make the reaction go: it is a *solvent*. And–even if you could do the reaction in a different solvent–the properties depend on the spinning process which is solvent dependent so you would get different bulk polymer properties.